# How can I save an image to a specific folder in React?

Tags: reactjs, database, image

i would like to know how can I save directly an image to specific path in react.

I would like to save images on this path 'http://localhost:8080/webdav/guest/document_library' and then take this link to store the reference of the image in a db.

I've searched on the net but I didn't understand how can I store my image directly on a path.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't modify files on the server using react, because react run in the browser

Answer (score 1):

There was already an answer that because React is ran at the browser, it cannot modify the local files.

I would recommend on developing a separated backend or using a full-stack framework such as Next.js or Remix. They both are React frameworks that allow you to control the same server that the react files are being served by.

Comment: I use Liferay backend and I have to save images to "documents and media" section of liferay that is available from desktop with the url I specified before, I would like to understand if I can pass image directly from user upload to that path and then save a reference on DB.